# ios15 status bar animation when setting a new root view controller in a another orientation

Tags: ios, animation, orientation, statusbar, ios15

I change the root view controller this way

```
window.rootViewController==viewController
```

The current root view controller is in landscape orientation, and with no status bar :

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
- (UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimationNone;
}
```

The new root view controller, is in portrait mode, with status bar displayed :

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return NO;
}
- (UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimationNone;
}
```

I don't want the transition is animated. `window.rootViewController==viewController` was working fine on iOS14, but since iOS15, when the root view controller is changed, I can see a weird animation of the status bar, transitioning from landscape to portrait. Any ideas how to not show this status bar animation ?

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**Short video of the transition** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBkEuHpdoSw)