# How can I forbid the rotation of status bar during the dismiss animation of a landscape viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I presented a landscape viewcontroller *A* on a portrait viewcontroller *B*, and hid the system status bar in *A* by overriding the `prefersStatusBarHidden` property to `false`.

After I called the `dismiss` method of *A*, it rotated back to *B*. Duration the rotation, the status bar of *A* appeared, scaled and rotated to the top of *B*.

**How can I forbid the rotation of status bar during the dismiss/present animation, make it stay at the top of *B*?**

Comment: This issue seems to happens only on iOS 15.  Also, this [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69842751/ios15-status-bar-animation-when-setting-a-new-root-view-controller-in-a-another)  includes a video showing the status bar animation that this question describes